# What x[i][j] = -i*cols - j ; is exactly doing in C

Tags: c

I don't understand what `x[i][j] = -i*cols - j ;` is exactly doing.. Can someone explain because i am beginner. I cant understand pointers `'*'`. Sorry for bad English.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    int a[5][5]; 
    readarray(5, 5, a); 
    printarray(3, 5, a); 
    return 0; 
}

void readarray(int rows, int cols, int x[rows][cols]) { 
    int i, j; 

    for (i = 0; i< rows; i++) 
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) 
            x[i][j] = -i*cols - j ; 
}

void printarray(int rows, int cols, int x[rows][cols]) { 
    int i, j; 
    for (i = 0; i< rows; i++) { 
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) 
            printf("%4d", x[i][j]) ; 
        printf("\n"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: `i` is negated then multiplied by cols then j is subtracted from that. This result is then stored in the 2 dimensional array using i and j as the indices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just populating the values of the array elements.

```
x[i][j] = -i*cols - j ; = x[i][j] = -i*5 - j ;

x[0][0] = 0
x[0][1] = -0*5 - 1 = -1
. . .
x[1][0] = -1*5 - 0 = -5
. . 
x[3][3] = -3*5 - 3 = -18
```

and so on..

Answer (score 4):

**`*` here is for the multiplication, not pointers.**

```
x[i][j] = -i*cols - j ;
```

There are several things happen here:

1. negative: `-i`
2. multiplication: `(-i) * cols`
3. substraction: `- j`
4. assignment: assign the result of the right side to `x[i][j]`.

---

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3515219/2589776) if you want to know the difference between using `*` for dereference and multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

I think only one multiplication is being performed. No pointers are being used.

```
i=2;
j=5;
cols = 5;

x[2][5] = -2 * 5 - 5
```